# Converting Json records to parquet using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to convert json input records as parquet format and send back to the output. i am getting below sample json records as input.

**input records:**

```
{'id': '37547594730892523208777', 'timestamp': 1518747, 'message': '10-05-2023 04:21:58.092 
[pool-2987-thread-1] INFO com.github.vjhdgk.loggenerator.SellRequest - id=32802,ip=188.219.135.214,
email=cbhdg3@gmail.com,sex=F,brand=redjh,name=imac Touch,color=cert,options=Disk 32Go,price=329.0'}
```

I am using below code in lambda function to convert above json logs to parquet format and send return back.

**index.py**

```
import base64
import gzip
import json
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('Received event: %s', event)

    output = []
    json_string = ''
    print(event['records'])
    for record in event['records']:
        print(record['data'])

        data = json.loads(gzip.decompress(
            base64.b64decode(record['data'])))
        print(data['logEvents'])

        for logEvents in data['logEvents']:
            print(logEvents)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data=processed_messages)
        print("df", df.head())
    
        # Convert the Pandas dataframe to an Arrow table
        table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
    
        # Write the Arrow table to a Parquet file in memory
        parquet_bytes = pa.BufferOutputStream()
        pq.write_table(table, parquet_bytes)

        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(json_string.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
        }
        output.append(output_record)

    print(json.dumps(output))

    return {'records': output}
```

can anyone help me with this code to convert above json records as parquet.
I don't want to write converted parquet records to any file, i just want them to return back as output. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not using `parquet_bytes` after writing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is already in a dataframe, I think `df.to_parquet(...)` should work.

Comment: can you please tell me where should i add **df.to_parquet(...)**  exactly

Comment: After `df = pd.DataFrame...` line, add `df.to_parquet(filename.parquet)`. Also, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html for a detailed example.

Comment: i don't want to write it to a file. i just want to convert it parquet records and return back